# вопрос про кириллицу закрыт как не по теме

Tags: поддержка

мой вопрос [Какую букву посоветуете для обозначения "ьы/йы", буквы типа я, ю, е, ё?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/449943/192185) закрыт (?), объявлен требующим правки, писать ответы на него уже нельзя.

я сейчас пошёл по ссылке, данной модераторами, https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic , и не вижу здесь ничего конкретно говорящего против моего вопроса.

> «Русский язык» — это сайт вопросов и ответов для лингвистов и
>   энтузиастов русского языка. Мы приветствуем вопросы, связанные с
>   различными разделами языкознания (будь то орфография или пунктуация,
>   синтаксис или грамматика, этимология или лексика), о его истории и
>   современном состоянии.

но, вот это место, вероятно, против моего вопроса:

> Абстрактные вопросы, больше подходящие для расслабленной личной
>   беседы, запрещены. Однако вы можете обсудить их в чате.

12:01 мск: отредактировал обсуждаемый вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Наш сайт не предназначен для исполнения запросов типа *Предложите свой рисунок для чего-то*. Мы обсуждаем реальные трудности и/или вообще явления языка. Возможно, вам стоит задать вопрос на сайте по конструированию языков: https://conlang.stackexchange.com/.